# Create a formula from text in other cells (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, syntax, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

[image]

Is it possible to merge the text of `E7` and `E8` so that it becomes a `SUBSTITUTE FORMULA` to return the value of `C7`?

Link to Spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JDOKIO2JncQRLdWR1vWfxcXR5z7IBOUJflNgbdMre7M/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**E14** would need to be:

```
=E7&CHAR(34)&C14&CHAR(34)&E8
```

and then this script will convert the string into valid formula from **E14** into **E16**:

```
function onEdit() { 
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Página1');  
var src = sheet.getRange("E14");
var str = src.getValue(); 
var cell = sheet.getRange("E16");
cell.setFormula(str);              
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Learning more each day from your tips!